# help with creating a page of equations using (LaTeX?)

Tags: equations

I am looking to create a template where I can quickly generate pages of basic math equations. LaTeX seems like a good place to start typesetting math equations but I am completely stumped with the syntax.

My thoughts are to first build a template, use python to generate the template code with random numbers, convert to PDF, then print. here is an example of what I have come up with so far, but trying to nest this within another table created issues.

```
\halign{\hfil # & # \hfil \cr 4\cr \underline{+2}\cr}
```

This produces [image: rendered example].

Are there any other languages or tools that I could use to meet my goals? I'm all ears.

Comment: What is exactly the problem that you are having? How to typeset some specific equation? How to layout a number of equations in a single page?

Comment: Both, I made headway typesetting the equation itself as documented by the code I provided, although I could very well be on the wrong track with that. I also would like to know the most effective way to layout a grid of equations.

Comment: You want them laid out like that - vertically?  And are they all to be of that sort: "x + y = [blank]" (only vertically)?  How would you like them laid out on the page?  In a grid?  Or can they be out of alignment?

Comment: Generally, when asking a question like this it helps to say what the goal is. Are you, perhaps, writing a page of exercises in arithmetic for school kids? Or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not so hackish, but still a bit, here are some ideas.

First define a new command to produce each of your equations. I used the `array` environment to do this.

```
\newcommand{\myeq}[2]{$\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}#1\\#2\\\hline\end{array}$}
```

Then arrange them on a page in a grid using a `tabular` environment.

```
\begin{tabular}{c@{\qquad}c}
\myeq{4}{+2} & \myeq{3}{\times 2} \\[2em]
\myeq{4}{+2} & \myeq{3}{\times 2}
\end{tabular}
```

[image: rendered example]

Note that you can give an optional argument to the `\\[..]` command in order to control the spacing between rows. And in the `@{..}` specifiers passed to `tabular` you can also use commands like `\qquad` or `\hspace{..}` to control the spacing between columns.

Answer (score 6):

You can even use LaTeX to generate your random numbers for you, using the `pgfmath` package, which is a part of [pgf/tikz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/).  Here is minimal example, using Juan's macros from his answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

% Juan's macro:
\newcommand{\myeq}[2]{$\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}#1\\#2\\\hline\end{array}$}

% Generate random integer between 1 and 9:
\newcommand{\rand}{\pgfmathrandominteger{\rndint}{1}{9}\rndint}

% The rest is from Juan's answer again, with numbers replaced by \rand:
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\qquad}c}
\myeq{\rand}{+\rand} & \myeq{\rand}{\times \rand} \\[2em]
\myeq{\rand}{+\rand} & \myeq{\rand}{\times \rand}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Then all you need to do is process the file by `pdflatex` to get the pdf.

Another option would be using `lua` to generate the numbers, and process the file by [luatex](http://www.luatex.org/). That will give you more flexibility, you can generate the numbers exactly the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

based upon the accepted answer I was able to put together a quick script that does exactly what I set out to do. I added logic to avoid carry-overs. Thanks for all your input.

```
#!usr/bin/python
import random

#cfg
numRows = 6
numColumns = 5
numPages = 1
equation_top_range=[1,30]
equation_bottom_range=[1,20]


# text blocks
multiply = r'\myeq{%s}{\times %s}'
add = r'\myeq{%s}{+%s}'
subtract = r'\myeq{%s}{-%s}'
page = r'''\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{%s}
%s
\end{tabular}
\end{center}'''
end_row = r'\\[6em]'
column = r'c@{\hspace{%sin}} '%(5.0/numColumns)



def hasCarryOver(top,bottom):
    a = b = c = d = 0
    if len(str(top))==2:a,b = int(str(top)[0]),int(str(top)[1])
    else:b = top

    if len(str(bottom))==2:c,d = int(str(bottom)[0]),int(str(bottom)[1])
    else:d = bottom

    if a+c > 9 or b+d > 9:return True
    else:return False



pages = []
for p in range(numPages):
    lines = []
    for x in range(numRows):
        line = []
        for y in range(numColumns):
            reject = True
            while reject:
                top = random.randrange(*equation_top_range)
                bottom = random.randrange(*equation_bottom_range)
                reject = hasCarryOver(top,bottom)

            line.append(add%(top,bottom))
        lines.append(' & '.join(line)+end_row)
    pages.append(page%("".join(column * column_number),'\n'.join(lines)))


body = r'''\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\myeq}[2]{$\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}#1\\#2\\\hline\end{array}$}

\DeclareMathSizes{10}{18}{12}{8}
\begin{document}
%s
\end{document}
'''%('\pagebreak'.join(pages))

print body
```

produces
[image]

Comment: I tried compiling this and got an error:

Comment: Changing 'column_number' to 'numColumns' solves the problem.